# With an angular form group is there a way of getting the forms event stream

Tags: angularjs

I want to perform an action each time a blur event happens on a form group bound control in angular.

I've seen the onBlur validation and it is an option. But I don't want to restrict the form control update events to be blurs. People may leave the cursor in the input and submit the form with a key control.

Something like an event observable where I would get a stream of the events the form group is using to perform its internal controls. Filter on the type (if 'blur') and call my function would be ideal.

Is there anything like this?

Also I don't want to use blur bindings from the DOM elements directly in the template. It would be so much extra work to make and maintain.

Comment: Hi, your first question for _AngularJS_ ? Maybe a [example] would help to illustrate what you want or don't want. So far I got: (a) no event-binding in HTML-templates (desired from JS-code). (b) multiple events to capture for a single form-element. (c) central event-listener that delegates based on event-type to suitable handler(-methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically in vanilla JavaScript you can register event-listeners to that target element via [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
var formInputElement = document.getElementById("myForm");

formInputElement.addEventListener("focus", myFocusFunction);
formInputElement.addEventListener("blur", myBlurFunction):
formInputElement.addEventListener("focusin", myFocusFunction);
formInputElement.addEventListener("focusout", myBlurFunction);
```

These will call your functions passed in as *listener* (callback function) for the *event-type* (e.g. `myBlurFunction` for an event-type identified by `blur`).

Comment: Its not "The angular way", but it works! I grabbed the form parent and traversed the children and bound listers to them. I can abstract this and get a general approach.

Thanks!

Comment: @Lockless "abstract this" demonstrates your experience ️ I guess we could work with a _generic_ [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) e.g. attached to the "form parent" (for _AngularJS_?) too, but then I need more context, details, an example. Might be a candidate for a second question ️

Comment: The actual use case is to save a form each time an input is blurred. The issue is that the inputs are built dynamically. I wanted to attach to the form group and hook into its event listeners like key down / up, click, focus and blur. But those are not exposed :(